# FLAGS Custom Field Error

Tags: apex, trigger

I am close to creating an alert system when a x amount of cases are created within 60 minutes.

I am trying to use the FLAGs package field to reduce the cases the Trigger pulls to only those with an age of 1 (60 minutes) or less but I keep getting the error that the Age Flag API does not exist even though I see it in the custom fields list.

```
trigger OutageAlert on Case (before insert) {
date today =system.today();
List<Case> numberofcases = [SELECT ID FROM CASE where CreatedDate>=:today && Flags_Case_Flag_Age__c<=1.00];
    for(case cas:trigger.new){
        if(cas.origin == 'Web - Email'){
            if(numberofcases.size() == 5) {
                cas.SendAlert__c = true;
            }
            if(numberofcases.size() == 10) {
                cas.SendAlert__c = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing to be able to use both the `CreatedDate && Flags_Case_Flag_Age__c` to only pull cases that meet the criteria?

I get this error:

> Variable does not exist: Flags_Case_Flag_Age__c

Comment: Variable does not exist: Flags_Case_Flag_Age__c is the error I am getting.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to add any clarifications. That is not what comments are for.

Comment: Missing doubleunderscore? flags__case_flag_age__c

Comment: Sadly that is not it cropredy :( even with the _ _ it still errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having issues with the namespace so I went another direction which has resolved the issue.

I created a new field called SLA and used the (NOW() - CreatedDate )*24 calculation to show a number related to hours then instead of the code looking for date and flag it now just looks for cases with under 1 SLA.

```
trigger OutageAlert on Case (before insert) {
date today =system.today();
List<Case> numberofcases = [SELECT ID FROM CASE where SLA__c<=:1];
    for(case cas:trigger.new){
        if(cas.origin == 'Web - Email'){
            if(numberofcases.size() == 5) {
                cas.SendAlert__c = true;
            }
            if(numberofcases.size() == 10) {
                cas.SendAlert__c = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now have it working and triggering as needed!

Answer (score 0):

If `Flags_Case_Flag_Age__c` is part of managed package then check the namespace and append the namespace before field API.

API Name will be: `namespace + Flags_Case_Flag_Age__c`;

Comment: Hi Santanu - How do I find the namespace? Sorry I am trying to ramp up my understanding of Salesforce.